# Confused about Kirchoff's voltage law and voltage drops

Tags: voltage

I am a beginner student in electricity and magnetism. I have troubles understanding the physics behind it and so have found myself stuck with this:

Kirchoff's voltage law, as I understand it, says that the electromotive force (voltage) that drives the current is equal to the total losses of voltage over the current.

How can this happen?

If we have a battery driving the current, isn't the voltage on its terminals always the same?

If the voltage drops over a resistor, will the current after it be moved by lesser force (smaller voltage)?

And most of all, doesn't that mean that the voltage after all drops will be 0, so what moves the current anyway?

I have no knowledge of AC, so this is DC related.

I am so sorry if this question is badly formatted or put together, but I couldn't word it differently.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to think of **voltage** as a measure of how much energy is available in some amount of charge. That is, how much work can the charge do? I'm going to suggest a simplified explanation of how voltage works, and I'm going to intentionally gloss over the detailed quantum and field aspects for now.

Like most things in nature, the charge will try to move from a higher energy level to a lower energy level. In a circuit, the only available path for that movement is through the elements that are connected together in a circuit. So the charge moves through elements like resistors, providing power and losing energy. In general, the electrical energy is converted to heat.

But there is another important requirement: the circuit wires and elements are like pipes full of water, in that for water to enter one end of the pipe an equal amount of water must be taken out of the other end of the pipe. When the charge is said to have a voltage of zero, it still flows because the higher energy charge is pushing it (rough analogy, I know).

Eventually, the circuit leads the charge back to the lowest voltage point. Something must then remove some charge from this lowest energy level so that more charge can flow in, and that is the job of the battery. A common battery converts chemical energy to electrical energy, lifting the charge at its low energy terminal to a higher energy level at the other terminal.

So, by creating the closed circuit path we have a way of converting chemical energy in the battery into other kinds of energy that we desire, such as heat, light, and mechanical energy. Kirchhoff's voltage law simply says that the amount of energy provided by the battery must equal the amount of energy lost in the resistors and wires and other elements as the charge makes its way back to the battery at a lower voltage.